# Different results with different differential rules

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

Let $y=\sec(x)$.
What is the value of ${dy\over dx}$ at $x={\pi \over 4}$

My answers:$$\sec(x)={1 \over \cos(x)}$$

`power rule` $\cos^{-1}(x)=>-\cos^{-2}(x)=>{-1 \over \cos^2(x)} => -1/0.5 =>-2$

`quotient rule (var. 1)` ${0\times\cos(x)+1\times \sin(x) \over \cos^2(x)} => {\sin(x) \over \cos^2(x)} => {\tan(x) \times {1 \over \cos(x)}} => 1 \times {1 \over{\sqrt{2} \over2}} => {2 \over \sqrt{2}}$

`quotient rule (var. 2)` ${0\times\cos(x)+1\times \sin(x) \over \cos^2(x)} => {\sin(x) \over \cos^2(x)} => {{\sqrt{2} \over2} \over ({\sqrt{2} \over2})^2}=>{{\sqrt{2} \over2} \over {1 \over 2}}=>\sqrt{2}$

Which one is right?

Comment: $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{(\sqrt{2})^{2}}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Also note that in your "Power Rule" line, you forgot to apply the chain rule. That is why that one is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You messed up the power rule:

$$ \mathrm{d}u^n = n u^{n-1} \mathrm{d}u $$

you forgot the factor corresponding to the derivative of $\cos(x)$. Or, depending on how you think of things, you forgot that you need to use the chain rule here in order to apply the power rule.

The other two answers you gave are actually the same:

$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2} $$

You need to be careful when comparing formulas with $\sqrt{2}$ (and a lesser extent with $\sqrt{3}$), because $2$ is a common number in formulas, and so you fairly often have situations like this where you can write the same number in different ways.

This is one of the reasons why people like to "rationalize the denominator".